# How to fill a view for LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

i first search to set `adapter` to a `LinearLayout` but as it's not possible so i use this :

```
LinearLayout LinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutListeNote);
    //LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    List<NoteObjet> notes = new ArrayList<NoteObjet>();
    notes.add(new NoteObjet(Color.BLACK, "Kevin"));
    notes.add(new NoteObjet(Color.BLUE, "Kevin"));
    notes.add(new NoteObjet(Color.GREEN, "Logan"));
    notes.add(new NoteObjet(Color.RED, "Mathieu"));
    notes.add(new NoteObjet(Color.GRAY, "Willy"));

    for (NoteObjet objet : notes){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.noteadapter, LinearLayout, false);
        // set item content in view
        LinearLayout.addView(view);
    }
```

but i don't know how to fill the view...
I just want a list of item like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz2aL.jpg) on horizontal [scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTx0g.jpg).
Thanks for help.

Comment: Why are you not just using a ListView or RecyclerView?

Comment: because i couldn't make horizontal listview, i never see RecyclerView, it's good ?

Comment: Use recycler view it has horizontal orientation.

Comment: please show your linearLayoutListNote xml file content

Comment: used to listview or recycled view bcoz easy to fill data and also set and get data